# Doctrine: Get auto increment ID before persist/flush

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, fixtures

I'm having trouble in Doctrine-Fixtures. I'd like to add a user and a email in another entity, but in relation to the user. So here is my process:

```
    // Create user
    $user1 = new User();

    // Create user email and add the foreign key to the user
    $user1Mail = new UserEmail();
    $user1Mail->setEmail('test@example.com');
    $user1Mail->setUser($user1);

    // Add attributes
    $user1->setEmail($user1Mail);
    // ...

    $manager->persist($user1Mail);
    $manager->persist($user1);
    $manager->flush();
```

I add the user of the email in `$user1Mail->setUser($user1);` before the persist, but the problem is, the user has no primary key --> the ID (auto increment). So to create the relation between the email and the user, the user needs to have a primary key to refer to.

I know the solution to create a unique token before and set this to the ID of the user, but I think this is a uncomfortable way because I need to check if the user ID is already in use.

Is there a good way to handle this?

// EDIT:
Here is the necessary entity relation:

User:

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var Application\CoreBundle\Entity\UserEmail
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(
     *  targetEntity="UserEmail",
     *  cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *  name="primaryEmail",
     *  referencedColumnName="id",
     *  nullable=false,
     *  onDelete="restrict"
     * )
     */
    private $email;

    // ...

}
```

UserEmail:

```
class UserEmail
{

    // ...

    /**
     * @var Application\CoreBundle\Entity\User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *  targetEntity="User",
     *  cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *  name="userID",
     *  referencedColumnName="id",
     *  nullable=false
     * )
     */
    private $user;


    // ...

}
```

As you can see, if you add a user you have to add a UserEmail also. But the UserEmail requires that the userID is already set, but it is only set if you persist the user into the db. How can I realize a fix for it?

Comment: Are you using the fixture bundle? http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html.  The bundle seems to address your use case.

Comment: Yes I am using it and it my problem is with it.

Comment: Read the section on sharing objects between fixtures.  But I suspect the real issue is your relations are not properly defined.  Your example should work.  The ORM will take care of ensuring that the user is actually written first to the database and that it's auto generated id then gets passed to the email.  Consider posting your orm files.

Comment: Run `app/console doctrine:schema:validate` to check for incorrect mapping definitions.

Comment: @JasperN.Brouwer The console reply: "OK- The mapping files are correct". The problem is not my Entity, but the workflow to insert a new user with a email in another relation entity. This other entity needs the user ID but as you can see in the example it is not set.

Answer (score 1):

I find it strange to see that your `User` has a OneToOne association towards `UserEmail`, and `UserEmail` has a ManyToOne association towards `User`, and those are 2 separate associations.

I think you'd rather have a single bidirectional OneToMany association:

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserEmail", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $emails;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param UserEmail $email
     */
    public function addEmail(UserEmail $email)
    {
        $this->emails->add($email);
        $email->setUser($this);
    }

    /**
     * @param UserEmail $email
     */
    public function removeEmail(UserEmail $email)
    {
        $this->emails->removeElement($email);
        $email->setUser(null);
    }

    /**
     * @return UserEmail[]
     */
    public function getEmails()
    {
        return $this->emails->toArray();
    }

    // ...
}

class UserEmail
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="emails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userID", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public setUser(User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return User[]
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I've put a `cascade` on `User::$emails`, so any changes to `User` get cascaded towards `UserEmail`. This will make managing them easier.

Using this would look something like this:

```
$email = new UserEmail();

$user = new User();
$user->addEmail($email);

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

**About foreign keys**

Doctrine will manage the foreign keys of your entities for you. You don't need to manually set them on your entities when using associations.

**Primary email**

Personally I would add a property to `UserEmail` to mark it as primary. You'll need a bit more logic in the entities, but managing them will become effortless.

Here's the additional code you need:

```
class User
{

    // ...

    /**
     * @param UserEmail $email
     */
    public function addEmail(UserEmail $email)
    {
        $this->emails->add($email);
        $email->setUser($this);

        $this->safeguardPrimaryEmail();
    }

    /**
     * @param UserEmail $email
     */
    public function removeEmail(UserEmail $email)
    {
        $this->emails->removeElement($email);
        $email->setUser(null);

        $this->safeguardPrimaryEmail();
    }

    /**
     * @param UserEmail $email
     */
    public function setPrimaryEmail(UserEmail $newPrimaryEmail)
    {
        if (!$this->emails->contains($newPrimaryEmail)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unknown email given');
        }

        foreach ($this->emails as $email) {
            if ($email === $newPrimaryEmail) {
                $email->setPrimary(true);
            } else {
                $email->setPrimary(false);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return UserEmail|null
     */
    public function getPrimaryEmail()
    {
        foreach ($this->emails as $email) {
            if ($email->isPrimary()) {
                return $email;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Make sure there's 1 and only 1 primary email (if there are any emails)
     */
    private function safeguardPrimaryEmail()
    {
        $primaryFound = false;

        foreach ($this->emails as $email) {
            if ($email->isPrimary()) {
                if ($primaryFound) {
                    // make sure there's no more than 1 primary email
                    $email->setPrimary(false);
                } else {
                    $primaryFound = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!$primaryFound and !$this->emails->empty()) {
            // make sure there's at least 1 primary email
            $this->emails->first()->setPrimary(true);
        }
    }

    // ...
}

class UserEmail
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isPrimary = false;

    /**
     * @internal Use 
     * @param bool $isPrimary
     */
    public function setPrimary($isPrimary)
    {
        $this->isPrimary = (bool)$isPrimary;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isPrimary()
    {
        return $this->isPrimary;
    }

    // ...
}
```

You'll probably notice `safeguardPrimaryEmail()`. This will make sure the primary-mark will remain consistent when adding/removing emails.

Using this is very simple:

- An email that's created is *not* primary by default.
- If it's the first email added to a user, it will automatically become primary.
- Additionally added emails will remain *not* primary.
- When the primary email is removed, the first remaining email will become primary.
- You can manually set another primary email by calling `User::setPrimaryEmail()`.

There are many variations to this concept possible, so just view this as an example and refine it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I want to clear my case: I want to set the primary email of the user in the User-entity. That's why it's a OneToOne-functionality. But the user can also have multiple email adresses (the only reason why I have another entity for user-emails). But at the register-process (that's what we are talking about) you set the primary email (for login confirmation, etc.) Is your example for this case?

Comment: That explains why you need an id in your case. This is something you could solve by first persisting the `User` with the associated `UserEmail`s, flush, then update `User::$email`, flush again.

Comment: But personally I would add a property `$isPrimary` to `UserEmail` (and not have that OneToOne association). This negates the hassle with the "double flush". I could give an example of this if you'd like.

Comment: yes, please. I can't believe this would be more simple, but maybe you're right.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Doctrine will generate the entity id when it's inserted into the database.
You can do it with an extra `flush()`:

```
$user1 = new User();
$manager->persist($user1);
$manager->flush();

// Create user email and add the foreign key to the user
$user1Mail = new UserEmail();
$user1Mail->setEmail('test@example.com');
$user1Mail->setUser($user1);

// Add attributes
$user1->setEmail($user1Mail);
// ...

$manager->persist($user1Mail);
$manager->persist($user1);
$manager->flush();
```

Or you can set the email mapping in your `User` class to cascade persist.
It means that if a new not persisted object is added to that object, then the new object will be saved as well.

I don't know the exact structure of the entites, but it would look like

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="user", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_email_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $userEmail
```

So if you set a new e-mail to the user it will be auto-persisted if you persist the `User` entity.

I would prefer the second method if it works. I hope it will help.

[Doctrine reference: Transitive persistence / Cascade Operations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

Comment: But that would go against my integrity rule: the users email can't be NULL. But in your first case, I would add the user and after that I would add the email, so at the first step the users email would be empty.

Comment: I'm afraid I cant understand your second solution. Could you expand it a little bit? I already have the cascade={"persist"} in the entity. But what does that have to do with my problem? I thought this is for allow update and insert queries in relation!?